Why .net 8 is not list in the target framework in VS 2022 - MacOs
Target framework 8 is not listing in the visual studio 2022 (17.6.1) version even after installing the .net 8 in my Mac machine. it still showing only 7
I was installed .net 8 and corresponding support visual studio version in Mac


VS (for Windows) only supports .NET 8 from version 17.8. Unfortunately VS for Mac is stuck at 17.6 and will never support anything beyond the .NET 8 preview and .NET 8 preview will also never be supported by MS.

Why are you using VS for Mac? If you want a full featured IDE, use Jetbrains Rider. If you use Xamarin Forms, it's already out of support so you'll have to migrate to a different stack. MS proposes MAUI but perhaps you should look at the open source Avalonia project for something less ... prone to cancellation

Yes I found the answer,
I have enabled the preview features in my visual studio. then the target framework listed both .net 7 & 8
Visual studio -> Preference -> in ur left side menu scroll to end -> Others-> Preview Features -> select (Use the .net 8 SDK if installed (requires restart) -> then restart the visual studio .
Now can see the both the .net 8 & 7

VS for Mac was discontinued. .NET 8 isn't a preview feature, it's the current LTS version. .NET 7 in the meantime is out of support

You saved my day. Thanks.

The real answer is that VS for Mac was discontinued along with Xamarin Forms. VS reaches End of Support on August 31, 2024. This was announced in August 2023.
.NET 7 is already out of support and so are Xamarin Forms. .NET 8 support was never added. As the retirement docs explicitly say

Microsoft doesn't plan to add support for .NET 8 or C#12 to Visual Studio for Mac. We won't extend to any other workloads before retirement either.

.NET 8 is the current Long Term Support version, not a preview feature. .NET 6, the previous LTS version reaches End Of Life on November 2024.
